# Make R show a floating point/double without abbreviation e+/-XX

Tags: r, floating-point, double

Sometimes `R` abbreviates a double with `e+/-XX` e. g. `4.940082e+01`. Because I need to write down some of those numbers I always need to add/substract zeros after/before the `.`. How can I force the `R` output to be `49.40082`?

Here’s an example:

```
a <- c(4.940082e+01, 4.011437e+02, 2.497144e+03, 1.952008e+02, 7.856008e+02,
3.413898e+01, 1.693910e+03, 1.728184e+01, 1.508768e+03, 8.385327e+01, 
5.482288e+02, 2.000204e+00, 5.754306e+01, 5.101145e+02, 1.948592e+01, 
1.851458e+03, 2.022429e+03, 9.942939e+01, 5.276865e+02, 8.163265e-04, 
1.034082e+03, 4.063104e+02, 6.653898e+01, 5.684818e+02, 3.669961e+02, 
1.326000e+03, 1.302859e+02, 5.754306e+01, 4.237716e+02, 1.647200e+03)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
as.numeric(format(4.940082e+01))
[1] 49.40082
```

Comment: Yes, but this will only work for single numbers I type directly into the command line. And in this case you won’t even need `as.numeric(format())`. I’ll include an example to show what I mean.